# Obtain actual --cores [N], --jobs [N], -j [N] value given from command line within the snakefile

Tags: snakemake

How is it possible to access all configuration values and corresponding parameters passed by command line to snakemake, within the snakefile?

For example by running:

```
snakemake -p --use-conda -j 16 --snakefile ../../Snakefile --configfile pipeline-test.config.yaml
```

In particular I wish obtain the number of available cores within the snakefile to be able to perform some computation with that value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.argv` within your *snakefile* to parse the command line parameters.

Comment: so can I use libraries such as argparse easilly parse command line parameters?